# IMAP / Jakarta Mail / Unexpected delete flag

Tags: java, email, jakarta-mail, imap

I have developed an application that monitors a mailbox and processes certain messages, which are identified by containing a specific keyword in the message subject. When such a message is received, it is deleted from the mailbox and triggers local processing. The code roughly looks like this:

```java
public void process() {
 
// Create properties
Properties properties = new Properties();
properties.put("mail.imap.host", host);
properties.put("mail.imap.port", port);
properties.put("mail.imap.socketFactory.port", port);
properties.put("mail.imap.partialfetch", "false");
properties.put("mail.imap.fetchsize", 36700160);
 
// Open
Session session = Session.getInstance(properties);
Store store = session.getStore("imap");
store.connect(emailAddress, password);
Folder folder = store.getFolder("INBOX");
folder.open(Folder.READ_WRITE);
 
// Count relevant messages
int count = 0;
 
try {
   // List messages
   for (Message message : folder.getMessages()) {
  String subject = message.getSubject();
  if (subject.contains(keyword)) {
 count++;
 message.setFlag(Flag.DELETED, true);
 
 // Do some local processing
  }
   }
} catch (MessagingException e) {
   // Log and ignore
} finally {
   // Expunge and close if a message was marked deleted
   try {
  if (count > 0) {
 folder.close(true);
  }
  store.close();
   } catch (MessagingException e) {
  // Log and ignore
   }
}
}
```

The problem is that some messages that should be processed are never processed. When activating the log on Jakarta mail (log com.sun.mail) I can see that the delete flag is being set for some messages and they are removed before they can be read by the method sketched above (which I see in the application log). As no other client is connected to the mailbox, I believe that my code might be the problem.

The problem only occurs irregularly when the application runs for several hours, so I am not able to provide a minimal example that can be used to reproduce the issue. My question is more of a general nature: has anyone also observed this behaviour when processing messages in a mailbox via IMAP with Jakarte Mail or with any other Email-API or protocol? Do you have any hints what the underlying issue might be? Do you see any issue with the pseudocode shown above?

Any help is very appreciated!

Comment: Just guessing... an exception is thrown at you set the deleted flag but before processing is done, perhaps?

Comment: Yes I receive some exceptions during processing. However the idea is to not proceed as this time and have the email processed the next time the receive method is called (e.g. in 30 seconds intervals). However, I do not understand how this can lead to delete flags on messages which have not been processed by my coding

Comment: It looks like you set \Deleted then do your local processing, according to your code here.

Comment: Thank you for your efforts. Please find my answer below

Answer (score 0):

I found a solution which solved the problem:
I did not close the folder and the store object in all cases after a receiving cycle:
If messages were actually received the folder was always closed with `folder.close(true)`.

Additionally I ensured now that in all cases (also exceptions) a method `close()` is called which contains:

```
    if (folder != null && folder.isOpen()) {
        folder.close(false);
    }
    
    if (store != null && store.isConnected()) {
        store.close();
    }
```

So far the issue did not occur again